# How to place 2 text boxes in div, next to each other in React without using flex?

Tags: reactjs

I have a div with 2 text boxes.

```
<div>
   <input ... />
   <input ... />
</div>
```

Issue is they get displayed below each other.

NOTE: I am not using React-Native, not using Flex.

How can I place them next to each other ?

Comment: Why did you not use a css tag? This is clearly a styling issue.

Comment: I am so new to react.. what is this CSS tag?

Comment: CSS is how you style html elements. Do you not have it set up in your project?

Comment: yeah but 'how' ? i have almost no styling

Comment: Gotcha. Will provide in an answer. I would definitely recommend using flexbox though. It is by far the easiest and most adaptive way of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer 1: Use Flexbox (or grid which is even more powerfull). Both of these are very powerful and wonderfully adaptive to the screen.

Answer 2: Use the hack that was used to do this before, using `float`. Give each of the input elements a style of `float: left` and add one div after with a css styling of `clear: all`, which will make it so the parent div has the correct height.